# Anonymous Type Error in Linq using Group, Sum, and selecting multiple fields of data after reading in spreadsheet with LinqToExcel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I'm reading in a spreadsheet using LinqToExcel, this part seems to work. The issue is that my spreadsheet has multiple rows with the same phone number, i need to group and sum the rows with the same phone number then export each unique row (with it's sum) to SQL. 
I'm stuck on the Linq / Lambda statements, I keep getting an Anonymous type error at my foreach loop. I'm pretty new to C# so any help is appreciated.

I'm using VS2013

**Here is my code:**

Using LinqToExcel to read in the spreadsheet: 
... also, on a previous project that is very similar to this i used a Dictionary like below, but in the previous project i was doing a lot of calculations that i had to add to the dictionary then enumerate over. So i'm wondering if I should keep this as a dictionary or use List....

```
public static class BillingPagerProcess
    {
        private static Dictionary<BillingPagerSource, decimal> UseLinqToExcel(string path)
        {
Dictionary<BillingPagerSource, decimal> dictionary = new       

Dictionary<BillingPagerSource, decimal>();

        var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory();
        excel.FileName = path;


        var pagerObject = (from p in excel.Worksheet<ModlPagers>("pagers")
                           where p.PagerPhoneNumber != "" // || 0000000000 
                           select p).ToList();
```

Here is where i'm doing the GroupBy

```
var pagerObjectGrouped = pagerObject.GroupBy(pg => pg.PagerPhoneNumber)
            .Select(s => new {
            holder = s.First().Holder, 
            recordId = s.First().RecordId, 
            pagerNumber =  s.First().PagerPhoneNumber, 
            sum = s.Sum(a => a.Amount)}).ToList();
```

*I would like to do something like this to shorten this up, but i'm unable to select multiple*

```
var pagerBillingObject = from x in excel.Worksheet<ModlPagers>("pagers").ToList()
                         group x by x.PagerPhoneNumber into pagerGrouped
                         select pagerGrouped.First(),
                         pagerGrouped.First().Holder, 
                         pagerGrouped.Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

And here is where i am doing the DB insert

```
NWSPortal.Services.NWSEntities pagerallcommit = new Services.NWSEntities();  
 // *this is where I get the Anonymous Type error - on my foreach statement*
        foreach (ModlPagers row in pagerObjectGrouped)     
        {
            NWSPortal.Services.Pager pagerall = new Services.Pager(); 

            pagerall.id = row.RecordId;
            pagerall.PagerPhoneNumber = row.PagerPhoneNumber; 
            pagerall.Holder = row.Holder; 


            pagerallcommit.Pagers.Add(pagerall);
        }
        pagerallcommit.SaveChanges();  



        return dictionary;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for each loop you are indicating row is of type ModlPagers, but its actually an anonymous type based on how your select is for pagerObjectGrouped. If you want to iterate over ModlPagers in your loop then you can make this change:

```
var pagerObjectGrouped = pagerObject.GroupBy(pg => pg.PagerPhoneNumber)
    .Select(s => new ModlPagers {
    Holder = s.First().Holder, 
    RecordId = s.First().RecordId, 
    PagerPhoneNumber =  s.First().PagerPhoneNumber, 
    Sum = s.Sum(a => a.Amount)}).ToList();
```

Notice the `new ModlPagers` part.

Comment: That makes sense. So if I add `new modlPagers` i am saying that `pagerObjectGrouped` is of type `modlPagers`. Thanks, i'll try this out in the a.m.

Comment: Actually pagerObjectGrouped will then be of type List<ModlPagers>

Comment: Thanks for you help, it works now. One adjustment I had to make for Linq to Excel was to add a `.ToList()`  after `var pagerObject = (from p in excel.Worksheet<ModlPagers>("pagers")` - otherwise i would get an error about linq to excel not supporting GroupBy - adding that first line to a list allows GroupBy in LinqToExcel.